# Can a Mono application be deployed using ClickOnce?

Tags: windows, deployment, installation, mono, clickonce

I am using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) to write a cross-platform application. On Windows, is it possible to deploy this application using ClickOnce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could use ClickOnce to deploy it to Windows machines. ClickOnce isn't going to work on anything else (of course). I don't know what tools you use for Mono, but you could try using MageUI or Mage to create a deployment out of the files and see if it works.

You also need these MIME types if you are targeting .NET 3.5:

.msp --> application/microsoftpath
.msu --> application/microsoftupdate

Answer (score 2):

You should associate these three file extensions with their corresponding MIME types in your web server:

- .deploy => application/octet-stream
- .manifest => application/x-ms-manifest
- .application => application/x-ms-application